# Preventing the repetition of two predict-originated words in a sentence

Tags: word-choice, redundancy, repetition

I have the following sentence:

> Researchers have noted the **predictive** power of features derived from students'
>   activity sequences when **predicting** if students will stop participating in online courses.

I know that *predicting* sounds a little repetitive. However, I could not find another way to phrase this. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not clear what is meant by *predicting engagement*. Do you mean *...when engaged in online courses*? (The phrase *Interaction sequences* is also somewhat puzzling!)

Comment: Sorry. These are domain terminologies. I updated it, does it look better?

Comment: You could replace *predicting if* with *assessing/forecasting/evaluating whether*.

Comment: What I mean is 'literally' predicting (using some statistical methods). So, might be forecasting? I just do not know if there is another way to phrase this sentence.

Comment: Consider *predictive power ... **regarding** when students ...*.

Comment: @Lawrence then how do you connect `of features derived from students' activity`? Could you please post an answer? I appreciate your help!

Comment: @renakre *done*

Comment: What about "...predictive features...used to determine whether students will stop..."?

Comment: @MichaelRAtchley thanks for the suggestion! I will consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current structure is

- the predictive power *of* (data) *when* (situation).

Since the *situation* is *predicting*, you end up using *predict* twice, once to specify the type of power, and then to elaborate on its application. The problem is that the elaboration also specifies the type of power, leading to the redundancy you've pointed out.

To use *predict* just once in that sentence, drop one of the 'specifications':

1. the power of (data) to predict (events); or
2. the predictive power of (data) regarding (events).

The problem with #2 is ambiguity: the word *regarding* can refer to *predictive power* or to the *data*. You can try to overcome this by adding a comma before *regarding*, producing:

- Researchers have noted the predictive power of features derived from students' activity sequences, regarding when students will stop participating in online courses.

I prefer #1 if the subtle change to the flavour of the sentence, from "the predictive power of features" to "the power of features to predict", is acceptable:

- Researchers have noted the power of features derived from students' activity sequences to predict when students will stop participating in online courses.

If assigning *power* to *features* seems a little out of place in an academic work, consider editing the sentence further. It might also be useful to make the *features* more prominent in the sentence, relegating the researchers to a reference:

- Features derived from students' activity sequences can be used to predict when students will stop participating in online courses (Rhea Searcher 2016).

Comment: @renakre Glad to help. :)

Comment: I wonder if `power` sounds a little strange there. Would `capacity` or `ability` be more appropriate? Or, it would not matter? What do you think?

Comment: @renakre Ah, that was the subtlety I mentioned. It's a bit stark to call it a *power*, isn't it? The question is how you wish to deal with the *features* - are they *used* or do they have *capabilities*? If the former, consider: "Researchers have used features ... to predict ...", or (if the specified researchers didn't actually use those features but just *noted* their potential) "Researchers have noted that features ... can be used to predict ...". This is part of the joy of editing - you end up saying what you really mean.

Comment: Oops, sorry - I edited my comment while you were making another. I think the edited comment addresses your last query.

Comment: Haha, that is right! :) How about: "Researchers have found that features... can be powerful predictors of ...". (see it all changed, but I guess this is what I really mean, as you said :)

Comment: There you go, you're getting the hang of it now. :)